# Move a pgfplot's minor grid on behind the major one

Tags: pgfplots, grid-typesetting

I noticed that the minor grid `y = const` coordinate lines are before the major one. How can I move the minor grid on behind the major one?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%===============================================================================
\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
    ]
    \begin{axis}[
            grid = both,
            major grid style={line width=.3pt,draw=brown!75},
            minor tick num = 5,
            minor grid style = {line width=.1pt,draw=brown!10},
           xtick={-6,...,6}, % This one works now
        ]
        \addplot+[blue, no marks, domain={-6:6}] {x^2};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For the record: I would have thought that this is the standard. To be sure if the current behavior is intended or a bug if filed a ticket in the [PGFPlots Tracker](https://sourceforge.net/p/pgfplots/bugs/231/).

Comment: @StefanPinnow Thank you for report!

Comment: I am about to ask the same question right now.

Comment: @Diaa unfortunately, there is no reply from the author of pgfplots yet

Comment: I think there may be some more serious (bugs) than this, which might delay the fix.

Comment: To me it seems that the order of drawing is:
Minor vertical grid lines,
major vertical grid lines,
minor horizontal grid lines,
major horizontal grid lines.